# Combine SELECT statements with aggregates in each statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, join, aggregate-functions

I want to combine 2 working sql statements into one, but i have no idea how to get this done.
I am working with excel/odbc and can just read the MS SQL SERVER.

First Statement:

```
 SELECT CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID, 
        Sum(Orders.OrdersEURO) AS 'Sum of OrdersEURO'
FROM MyDataBase.dbo.CustomerLocal CustomerLocal, 
     CopelandDatabase.dbo.Orders Orders
WHERE Orders.LocalCustomerID = CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID 
      AND Orders.Plant = CustomerLocal.Plant 
      AND ((CustomerLocal.IntExtCust In ('E')))
GROUP BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
```

and the second statement is:

```
SELECT Sales.LocalCustomerID, 
SUM (CASE WHEN Sales.DateOfInvoice BETWEEN{ts '2012-10-01 00:00:00'} AND {ts '2013-09-30 00:00:00'} 
THEN Sales.SalesEURO
ELSE 0
END) AS Sales2013 ,
SUM (CASE WHEN Sales.DateOfInvoice >= {ts '2013-10-01 00:00:00'}  
THEN Sales.SalesEURO
ELSE 0
END) AS SalesYearToDate
FROM "dbo"."Sales"
Where Sales.DateOfInvoice >= {ts '2012-10-01 00:00:00'}
Group By Sales.LocalCustomerID
ORDER BY Sales.LocalCustomerID
```

Wished outcome (columns):

```
LocalCustomerID, Sales2013, SalesYearToDate, Sum of OrdersEURO
```

How to start the integration combination of the two?, at the moment i just run both in excel and vlookup the rest.

EDIT: replaced the 2nd statement, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: both statement are same...! what is second sql statement ?

Comment: What is the name of the column that we derive YTD and 2013 data from? Do you want it to switch over to 2014 at some point? hint: it would be better if `Sales2013` was called `SalesFullYear`

Comment: Where do Sales2013 and SalesYearToDate come from?

Comment: Messed the statements up, i should have payed more attention. i am very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join should work:

```
Select a.LocalCustomerID, b.Sales2013, b.SalesYearToDate, a.[Sum of OrdersEURO]
from
(
SELECT CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID, 
       Sum(Orders.OrdersEURO) AS 'Sum of OrdersEURO'
FROM MyDataBase.dbo.CustomerLocal CustomerLocal, CopelandDatabase.dbo.Orders Orders
WHERE Orders.LocalCustomerID = CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID AND Orders.Plant =   
CustomerLocal.Plant AND ((CustomerLocal.IntExtCust In ('E')))
GROUP BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
) a
JOIN
(
SELECT Sales.LocalCustomerID, 
SUM (CASE WHEN Sales.DateOfInvoice BETWEEN{ts '2012-10-01 00:00:00'} AND {ts '2013-09-30 00:00:00'} 
THEN Sales.SalesEURO
ELSE 0
END) AS Sales2013 ,
SUM (CASE WHEN Sales.DateOfInvoice >= {ts '2013-10-01 00:00:00'}  
THEN Sales.SalesEURO
ELSE 0
END) AS SalesYearToDate
FROM "dbo"."Sales"
Where Sales.DateOfInvoice >= {ts '2012-10-01 00:00:00'}
Group By Sales.LocalCustomerID
) b
ON a.LocalCustomerID=b.LocalCustomerID
ORDER BY a.LocalCustomerID
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN' and also Incorrect Syntax near 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

try to use union statement

```
SELECT CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID, 
    Sum(Orders.OrdersEURO) AS 'Sum of OrdersEURO'
FROM MyDataBase.dbo.CustomerLocal CustomerLocal, CopelandDatabase.dbo.Orders Orders
WHERE Orders.LocalCustomerID = CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID AND Orders.Plant =     CustomerLocal.Plant AND ((CustomerLocal.IntExtCust In ('E')))
GROUP BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
Union
SELECT CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID, 
       Sum(Orders.OrdersEURO) AS 'Sum of OrdersEURO'
FROM MyDataBase.dbo.CustomerLocal CustomerLocal, CopelandDatabase.dbo.Orders Orders
WHERE Orders.LocalCustomerID = CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID AND Orders.Plant =   
CustomerLocal.Plant AND ((CustomerLocal.IntExtCust In ('E')))
GROUP BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerLocal.LocalCustomerID
```

Comment: it's not possible to give an answer yet because there is a mistake in the question: both SQL statements are the same.